# Display all positive solutions of equation x1+x2+...+xk = n

Tags: algorithm, combinations

Below is the program that displays all positive solutions of equation x1+x2+...+xk = n, where k and n are positive integers:

```
func solution(k: Int, n: Int) {
    if k > n || k <= 0 {
        print("No solution")
    } else 
        if k==1 {
            print(n)
        } else {
            for i in 1...(n-k+1) {
                print(i, terminator:"")

                solution(k-1, n: n-i)
                print("")
            }
        }
}
solution(4, n: 4)
```

This program runs well with n = 4 and k = 1,2,4, but it displays incorrectly when k = 3. Can somebody helps find the mistake?

Comment: I'd say when you deal with loop it starts with 0.

Comment: @FrancisSaul zero is not positive number ...

Comment: the recursive call looks suspicious should not it be just `solution(k-1, n-i)` instead? btw what language is this add the TAG ....

Comment: @Spektre: 0 is neither positive nor negative. bdw, what is your point?

Comment: @FrancisSaul the `for` loop can not start from zero because it is not a valid solution for this task ...

Comment: Which language is this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is for n = 4 and case k = 1, 2, 4, there is only one solution for each i, so your `print(i, terminator:"")` work correctly.

However, for case k = 3, for example, after printing 1 at k = 3, so there are more than one correct cases: `(1 , 2, 1)` or `( 1, 1, 2)`, which means, just one command `print(1, terminator:"")` at `k = 1` will not be sufficient.

Image the printing routine will be smt like:

```
at k = 3, i = 1, print 1

at k = 2, i = 1, print 1

at k = 1, i = 2, print 2

So, at this time, we have (1, 1, 2), looks good.

However, when we backtrack to k = 2, i = 2, print 2

at k = 1, i = 1, print 1,

So, we only have (2, 1), which is not correct.
```

One simple way to fix this is rather than printing at each recursive step, you just store all result in one array, and print this array when k reaches 0